# 57-584 tire and (50,60,62)-584 tube

Tags: tire, germany

I have a tube (fits 27.5", 28" and 29"), and a 27,5" tire with the dimensions 
*57-584 (27.5/2.25, 650B)*. But the package of the tube only shows suitability for the dimensions (27.5"):

1. 50-584  27.5 x 2.00  650B
2. 60-584  27.5 x 2.35  650B
3. 62-584  27.5 x 2.40  650B

Can I use the tube for my tire? What would be possible consequences?


The tube and tire are from *Schwalbe SV-19*

Comment: Tubes are elastic and fit different tyre sizes and even rim sizes within a reasonable range. Also 27.5 and 650B are the same dimension but in a different system. Look here for comparison tables: https://www.sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html#iso

Comment: Please do not answer in comments

Comment: I've never seen a inner tube that fits several wheel rim diameters. What makes you think this tube can fit 27.5", 28" and 29" wheels (ETRTO 559, 584, 622)?

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus [That's](https://www.google.de/shopping/product/13965795286769766610/image?q=schwalbe+sv+19&oq=schwalbe+sv+19&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.5745j0j9&client=ms-android-samsung&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8&prds=cid:13965795286769766610,sgro:iv&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwikrvXt3sDeAhUEMewKHRwlD6UQ-K4BCK0B) the tube.

Comment: Link does not work for me (I'm in the US), but you are right. I looked up the SV-19, Schwalbe's website says it fits 584mm and 622mm rims. (29" and 28" both refer to 622 rims, 29" is an MTB term, 28" a road term)

Comment: Also I just noticed you did *not* say the tube fitted 26" (559mm) wheels - my mistake there

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus link works fine for me from Pacific and from Texas and LA.

Comment: Uh, 57 is between 50 and 60.  If the tube is good for 50 and good for 60, why wouldn't it be good for 57??

Comment: @DanielRHicks I wasn't sure what the exaxt meaning of those numbers (xy-584) is. I have always used those tubes, too, but I just wanted to make sure that  there is no problem.

Comment: The 50/60/57 is the (approximate) width of the pumped up tire in millimeters. Hence @DanielRHicks comment, which is completely true.

Answer (score 6):

'584', '27.5' and '650B' are all the same thing, specified in different wheel size systems.

These size wheels originated in the older French wheel size system and are called 650B (650mm being the diameter of wheel and tire). ETRTO (European Tire and Rim Technical Organization) specifies wheel rim diameters in millimeters (584mm in this case). Mountain bikers call these 27.5" (the approximate diameter of the wheel and a fat MTB tire).

The tire width specifications of your tire and the tube are given in both millimeters and inches. Tube min tire width is 50mm / 2.00", max is 62mm / 2.40"

Your tire width is 57mm / 2.25" so the tube will work with it just fine.